# Updated Methods for deriving the "front month equivalent" series in commodities derivatives

Tags: hedging, commodities

> It is common in commodities markets to hold many positions, both long
> and short, across a range of contract months beginning in the prompt
> month to five or more years out. [My question is:] What is the
> industry standard model for condensing a strip of forward contracts
> into a single exposure number "FME" such that it is reasonable to
> approximate PNL by taking FME*spot price. (presume you are given a
> corr/cov matrix)?

Source: [Methods for "prompt month equivalent" exposure in commodities forwards/futures markets](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/14467/methods-for-prompt-month-equivalent-exposure-in-commodities-forwards-futures-m/14472#14472?newreg=39caead007924ac0b91ba41117dfef8f) Quantfinance

I've explored the above post and the below article regarding the topic, however, none seem to be an accurate depiction of the front month hedge ratio in current market conditions. Anyone find anything more recent to solve this? Thanks in advance!

I understand the author's suggestion as multiplying the correlation of log returns by the ratio of implied volatilities of each tenor to the implied volatility of the prompt month contract. To my understanding this is supposed to be the FME value to apply to the delta position in our book to derive the front month hedge. However, the series that comes out of this calculation doesn't seem to fit the fundamentals of the current market. Any help or clarification on this would be greatly appreciated.

https://www.risk.net/sites/default/files/import_unmanaged/risk.net/data/eprm/pdf/january03/technical.pdf

Comment: Can you briefly summarize why you feel the method "does not fit current market conditions"? Also what commodity market are you working with?

Comment: I get a series that comes out with numbers way to high to be an FME factor. When front month contract has FME of 1, one would expect the rest of the curve to decay. Instead I can get late cal25 FME factors considerably higher than that of say summer 24's. This just doesn't make sense. I assume I'm missing some step in the overall calculation but I've been stomped in figuring it out. I'm working primarily in energy forwards/swaps, mainly power and gas.